# angular and history.pushstate performs redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, pushstate

I have regular site that inside it there is a lot of angular code.

** this is not a single page app, the site simply uses angular for js.

Now I want to use:

```
history.pushstate(null, null, "/somewhere");
```

so my problem is this:
- when the command is ran inside angular service|controllers it changes the url and redirects.
- when I run the command outside of angular objects, just in the global scope it works well, simply changes the url and that's all.

What exactly angular is doing that redirects the page after the command?
and how do I cancel the redirection?

example code:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller(function($scope) {

        //this perform an unneeded redirect
        history.pushstate(null, null, "whatever");
    });

//but if the code is here, it works perfectly fine
history.pushstate(null, null, "whatever");
```

Comment: I have similar problem, @Tzook did you find any solution

Comment: Nothing @Sawood this is angular 1. Moved from it already

Comment: thanks, I'll also check for alternate solution.